# How to write code that splits all images in a folder into 4 parts each and saves them?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, data-preprocessing

So, I have a folder with a bunch of images and I want each of those images to be split into 4 parts. I wrote the following code below, but it doesn't seem to work. I get no errors but I get no output. The code works for individual images without the loop though

```
i = 0
limit = 10000 
for imageName in glob.glob('Path/*.jpg'): 
  if i < limit:
    img_path = imageName
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    imName= Path(img_path).stem

    height = img.shape[0]
    width = img.shape[1]

    width_cutoff = width // 2
    left1 = img[:, :width_cutoff]
    right1 = img[:, width_cutoff:]


    img = cv2.rotate(left1, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)

    height = img.shape[0]
    width = img.shape[1]

    width_cutoff = width // 2
    l2 = img[:, :width_cutoff]
    l1 = img[:, width_cutoff:]

    l2 = cv2.rotate(l2, cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)

    cv2.imwrite(imName+"part_left_2.jpg", l2)

    l1 = cv2.rotate(l1, cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)

    cv2.imwrite(imName+"part_left_1.jpg", l1)


    img = cv2.rotate(right1, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)

    height = img.shape[0]
    width = img.shape[1]

    width_cutoff = width // 2
    r4 = img[:, :width_cutoff]
    r3 = img[:, width_cutoff:]

    r4 = cv2.rotate(r4, cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)

    cv2.imwrite(imName+"part_right_4.jpg", r4)

    r3 = cv2.rotate(r3, cv2.ROTATE_90_COUNTERCLOCKWISE)

    cv2.imwrite(imName+"part_right_3.jpg", r3)

  i = i + 1
```

So, imageName contains the path of each image in each iteration.
i helps us go to the next iteration until we reach the last image
imageName is used to define img_path which uses the image path to cut the image into 4 parts

Comment: Files are written to the current directory, not the source directory. Maybe you think there’s no output because you didn’t look in the right place? Add some `print` statements to your code to observe its behavior.

Comment: Also, what’s with all the rotating? You can cut vertically too, you know?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for the reply and suggestions. I can't seem to find the images anywhere. Another point to note is that my folder has about 100 images that need to be split and the code finishes executing in under a second. I would imagine that actually slicing 100 images would take a few seconds at least. So, I have a sneaky suspicion that there's some logical error where the images aren't even being considered

Comment: So add a `print("Reading", img_path)` statement before your `imread` call, an `print("Writing", imName+"part_left_2.jpg")` etc. statements before each `imwrite` call. Then you can see what it's doing, and if it's doing anything at all. Do you even know for sure if your `glob.glob('Path/*.jpg')` call returns the files you want?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I found my mistake. The images are stored as 'imgname.JPG' but the path I specified was 'imgname.jpg'